# adding bower as devDependency in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I'm using node.js and bower. I want to install bower at global level. Also, I need it to be included in the `package.json` file under `devDependency`.

so I tried,

```
npm install -g bower --save-dev
```

Bower is installed successfully but I don't see the package.json file is getting updated. What could the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably because you're installing it globally. When you install it globally, it won't get saved locally.

To be able to use it locally, through `npm init`, you can include it in the `devDependencies`, and then reference it as `./node_modules/.bin/bower`, since npm stores executables there.

Comment: It's bad. Actually I'm expecting when the developer download the package.json file and run npm init everything (both server-side and client-side packages) should get downloaded and installed. I don't think it's possible now.

Comment: Sure it is. You can run the local copy of bower from `./node_modules/.bin/bower`.

Comment: You are right! After installing locally the package.json is getting updated.