# Can bower.json be chained to npm install in package.json?

Tags: npm, electron, npm-install, package.json

New to Electron I've seen a few dependencies installed with Bower. After referencing the Bower [documentation](https://bower.io/) it shows an install of Bower globally with:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Instead I wanted to learn if I could install everything at one executable command. After reading "[adding bower as devDependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177442/adding-bower-as-devdependency-in-package-json)" I found that I could save it as a `devDependencies` with:

```
npm i bower --save-dev
```

then I could create a *bower.json* file like the *package.json* file from "[Creating Packages](https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/)" and in my *bower.json* I have:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^5.7.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  }
```

on the same level as *package.json* but when I research to see if I can install everything with `npm i` instead of having to use:

```
bower i
```

In *package.json* is there a way to chain `bower i` to `npm i` so when the the project is cloned it will install everything including the Bower packages? I've been unable to find if this has been asked before from my searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's enabled using a feature called `scripts` in `npm`. `npm` provides hooks for you to trigger your script. I recommend using the `postinstall` hook which will run `bower i` after you run `npm i`.

Adapting from the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#examples):

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts" :
  { 
    "postinstall" : "bower i"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `postinstall` and `install`? Is it only for the delay Id assume and the `bower i` would install everything from *bower.json*?

Comment: @Gʀɪᴍ my understanding is that `install` by default installs the npm dependencies but can be overridden to  do additional/alternate actions.

PS: Anyone knowing any better, please correct me if I'm wrong.